# $\operatorname{Ext}$ and injectives, respectively projectives

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

If $\operatorname{Ext}^{ 1}_{R}(A,B) = 0  $ for all $R$-Mod $A$ then $B$ is injective ?

If $\operatorname{Ext}^{ 1}_{R}(A,B) = 0  $ for all $R$-Mod $B$ then $A$ is projective ?

Comment: Yes to both questions, which are part of exercises 2.5.1 and 2.5.2 of Weibel's [An introduction to homological algebra](http://books.google.it/books?id=flm-dBXfZ_gC). Is this *homework*? Could you please tell us what are your thoughts about those questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $R$-module. Then $A$ is projective if and only if the functor 
$$Hom_R(A,-): R-Mod \longrightarrow R-Mod$$
is exact (show that the functor $Hom_R(A,-)$ is left exact when $A$ is an arbitrary $R$-module; try to prove that $Hom_R(A,-)$ is right exact when $A$ is projective).

If $A$ is projective then
$$0 \longrightarrow A \overset{id_A}{\longrightarrow} A \longrightarrow 0$$
is a projective resolution for $A$. Try to use this to see that $Ext_R^i(A,B)=0$ for all $B$ in $R-Mod$ and all $i \geq 1$.

Conversely, suppose $Ext_R^1(A,B)=0$ for all $B \in R-Mod$. Try to apply the long exact sequence for (contravariant) cohomological $\delta$-funtors to a short exact sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow D \longrightarrow E\longrightarrow 0$$
and see what you can get.

Note that your second statement still holds in abelian categories with enough projectives. In fact, we have that:

**Projective dimension lemma:**
 Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category with enough projectives. The following assertions are equivalent for $A \in Obj{\mathcal{A}}$:

- $proj.dim\, {A} \leq d$;
- $Ext_{\mathcal{A}}^{i}(A,B)=0$ for all $i \geq d+1$ and all $B \in Obj{\mathcal{A}}$;
- $Ext_{\mathcal{A}}^{d+1}(A,B)=0$ for all $B \in Obj{\mathcal{A}}$;
- If
  $$
  0 \longrightarrow
    M_d \longrightarrow
      P_{d-1} \longrightarrow
        \cdots \longrightarrow
          P_1 \longrightarrow
            P_0 \longrightarrow
              A \longrightarrow
  0
  $$
  is a resolution of $A$ with $P_i$ projective for $0 \leq i \leq d-1$ then the syzygy $M_d$ is projective.

The corresponding statements for injectives follow by dualisation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove that $A$ projective and $B$ injective imply, respectively, that $\hom_R(A,-)$ and $\hom_R(-,B)$ are exact functors.

---

If $B$ is an injective module and $f\colon M\to N$ is an injective map of $R$-modules, then for every $\alpha\in\hom_R(M,B)$ there is a $\beta\in\hom_R(N,B)$ such that

[image: diagram for injective module]

i.e. $f^*\colon\hom_R(N,B)\to\hom_R(M,B)$ is surjective, so $\hom_R(-,B)$ is exact. Therefore the right derived functors $R^i\left(\hom_R(-,B)\right)$ are null for all $i>1$.

Dually for $A$ projective.

Comment: Or, equivalently, that every short exact sequence with $A$ injective at the beginning ($C$ projective at the end) splits. This, in my opinion, is the best way to see those to be the trivial group.

Comment: I worked out my hint. Recall that $\hom$ always is left exact, so you just need to prove right exactness.